# Gather azure profile picture in Java After SAML login

Tags: java, azure, microsoft-graph-api, saml-2.0

After a SAML login I want to gather the user profile picture. Unfortunately that is not in the SAML attribute. I tried to look for a solution and I found that I have to use graph api.

So I tried to use the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value call.

Before that I needed a Bearer Token

I find that I can call https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token
using these parameters in form-data

```
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id=<the Client Id of my application registered in Azure>
client_secret<the Client secret generated in Azure of my application>
scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

After calling that I get a bearer token successfully.
But when I use it in the /photo/$value call I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"NoPermissionsInAccessToken\",\"message\":\"The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.\",\"innerError\":{\"requestId\":\"zzz\",\"date\":\"2020-11-09T07:22:06\"}}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-09T07:22:06",
            "request-id": "zzzz",
            "client-request-id": "xxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is there any other method I can use in Java to get the profile picture?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please giving both permissions below under application permissions and grant admin consent.

And use `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value`.Please refer to  [client-creds-grant-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)and [auth-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).
[image]

-----------------***UPDATE***------------------

[a java console app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java).

This is an example of a page-only lists ad users.Just put the following access token in ***var accessToken="your access token******"******;and you can run it.

```
<html>

    <style>
        .userItem {
          background-color:lightgrey; 
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        
        .userItem p {
          display: inline-block;
          width:25%
        }

        .LicenseItem {
          background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 45%;
          overflow: auto;
        }
        
        .LicenseItem p {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 20%;
      
        }
     

        .loadMore {
            background-color: aqua;
            font-style: italic; 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 15px;
        }
        </style>

    <body>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="userListView">
            <div class="userItem" style="background-color: aqua;font-style: italic;">
                <hr>
                <p> user display name </p>
                <p> user email address </p>
                <p> user principal name </p>  
            </div>
            <div id="userList"></div>
            <div id="loadMore" class="loadmore"></div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var accessToken="your access token*********";
        var ItemView = " <div id='@id' class='userItem'><hr><p id='@id-obj' style='display:none'>@obj</p><p > @displayName </p><p > @mail </p><p > @upn </p></div>"
        function initPage(){
            $("#loadMore").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=10',
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": 'application/json', 
                    "Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var userlist = data.value;
                    var nextpageUrl = data['@odata.nextLink'];
                    if(nextpageUrl){
                        $("#loadMore").append("<div onclick='loadMore(\""+ nextpageUrl  +" \")'>load more...</div>");
                    }
                    userlist.forEach(element => {
                        var view = ItemView.replace(/@id/g,element.id).replace("@displayName",element.displayName).replace("@mail",element.mail).replace("@upn",element.userPrincipalName).replace("@obj",JSON.stringify(element));
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(element));

                        $("#userList").append(view);
                    });
                },
                error:function(data){
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText)
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="ERROR:" + response.error.message;
                }
            });
        }

        function loadMore(url){

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'get',
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": 'application/json', 
                    "Authorization":"Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var userlist = data.value;
                    var nextpageUrl = data['@odata.nextLink'];
                    
                    if(nextpageUrl){
                        $("#loadMore").empty();
                        $("#loadMore").append("<div onclick='loadMore(\""+ nextpageUrl  +" \")'>load more...</div>");
                    }
                    userlist.forEach(element => {
                        var view = ItemView.replace(/@id/g,element.id).replace("@displayName",element.displayName).replace("@mail",element.mail).replace("@upn",element.userPrincipalName).replace("@obj",JSON.stringify(element));
                        $("#userList").append(view);
                    });
                },
                error:function(data){
                    var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText)
                    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML="ERROR:" + response.error.message;
                }
            });
        }
        initPage();

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: I'll ask the administrator to add the application permission, But why I can't use delegate permission?

Comment: @MarioDeCarli You are using client_credentials flow,it does not support api calls that require the user to log in.The /me endpoint needs a user to login.If you want to use this endpoint,you can use other flow to obtain a token like auth-code flow or resource owner password flow(ROPC flow).

Comment: As I'm loggin in via SAML why I can't get a token in the assertion so I can access user information?

Comment: You were right. But now that I have the image in response how do I write it to browser?

Comment: @MarioDeCarli You need a java web app integrate with ad  and unfortunately I'm not familiar with Java.You ask another question for better help,I updated some information in the answer.If my previous answers were helpful to you, you could accept them as answer, which would be helpful to other community members.:)